# split multiline textbox text with new line depending on string length .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

I have a multiline textbox and I want to make an array of strings, However I would like to concatenate a new line when string has more than 60 chars.

So supposing I have a text:

```
A geologic period is one of several subdivisions of geologic time enabling cross-referencing of rocks and geologic events from place to place. These periods form elements of a hierarchy of divisions into which geologists have split the earth's history.
```

be converted to:

```
A geologic period is one of several subdivisions of geologic \n
time enabling cross-referencing of rocks and geologic events \n
from place to place. These periods form elements of a        \n
hierarchy of divisions into which geologists have split the  \n
earth's history.
```

So to do so I was plannig to use

```
array_strings = myMultilineText.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

and then loop through each string in array like

```
 For index = 0 To array_strings.GetUpperBound(0)
    If array_strings(index).Length < 60 Then
        MessageBox.Show(array_strings(index))
    Else
       'add new line...
    End If
 Next
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You want to split by new line, but there is no new line in your input string. You're asking for better way, but I'm not sure your current one does work at all.

Comment: You need to use TextWrapping property of the textbox and set it to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your text to be wrapped in a `TextBox` you can just set the "WordWrap" property to True. But in case you want an algorithm you can use this code in c# (you can convert it to VB if you want, it's so simple)

c# Code:

```
        string longString = "Your long string goes here...";

        int chunkSize = 60;
        int chunks = longString.Length / chunkSize;
        int remaining = longString.Length % chunkSize;
        StringBuilder longStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < chunks * chunkSize; index += chunkSize)
        {
            longStringBuilder.Append(longString.Substring(index, chunkSize));
            longStringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        if (remaining != 0)
        {
            longStringBuilder.Append(longString.Substring(index, remaining));
        }

        string result = longStringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

VB Code (Converted via [developerfusion Conversion Tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)):

```
Dim longString As String = "Your long string goes here..."

Dim chunkSize As Integer = 60
Dim chunks As Integer = longString.Length \ chunkSize
Dim remaining As Integer = longString.Length Mod chunkSize
Dim longStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
Dim index As Integer
index = 0
While index < chunks * chunkSize
    longStringBuilder.Append(longString.Substring(index, chunkSize))
    longStringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    index += chunkSize
End While
If remaining <> 0 Then
    longStringBuilder.Append(longString.Substring(index, remaining))
End If

Dim result As String = longStringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
```

Comment: Good work. While the OP did not mention it, if wrapping requires cutting a word in the middle, it would not look good. . Also absent from requirements is what to do about new line char already in the multi-line textbox. Currently your code ignores it.However, these are requirements issues and not a problem with your code.